# Query with Where before GroupBy

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have an entity like this:

```
public class Event
{
    public string Code;
    public DateTimeOffset DateTime;
}
```

I want to filter by `Code` and then group by `DateTime.Date`. I tried this:

```
var results = session
    .Query<Event>()
    .Where(e => e.Code == "123")
    .GroupBy(e => e.DateTime.Date)
    .ToList();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Raven.Client.Exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Field 'Code' isn't neither an aggregation operation nor part of the group by key
Query: from Events group by DateTime.Date where Code = $p0
Parameters: {"p0":"123"}
```

It can be seen from the resulting query that the `where` clause is being added after the `group by` clause, which explains the error.

So how do I perform this query in RavenDB?

EDIT:

The `code` "123" that I used was just an example. I need it to be a variable that is passed to the query, like this:

```
var results = session
    .Query<Event>()
    .Where(e => e.Code == code)
    .GroupBy(e => e.DateTime.Date)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, learn about the **[dynamic aggregation query syntax](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/auto-indexes/auto-map-reduce-index)** in:
 
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/auto-indexes/auto-map-reduce-index

**But**, in your case you need to define a **Static Map-Reduce Index** to calculate this for you:
(Sum up the number of (filtered) documents per unique Date)
i.e.

```
 public class Result
 {
     public string  Date { get; set; }
     public int NumberOfDocs { get; set; }
 }

 Map = events => from event in events
     where event.Code == "123"
     select new Result  
     {           
        Date = event.DateTime.Date
        NumberOfDocs = 1         
     }     

 Reduce = results => from result in results  
     group result by result.Date into g
     select new Result 
     {
        Date = g.Key,
        Count = g.Sum(x => x.NumberOfDocs )
     }
```

==> Learn about **[Static Map-Reduce Index](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/static-indexes/map-reduce-index)** in:
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/static-indexes/map-reduce-index 
**Follow the detailed Walkthrough..**

### ----------

**Update**:
You can use the following map-reduce index that aggregates the number of documents *per Code & Date 'couple'*, and then you can query with 'Code'

```
public class Result
{
      public string Code { get; set; }
      public string  Date { get; set; }
      public int NumberOfDocs { get; set; }
}

         Map = events => from event in events        
             select new Result  
             {          
                Code = event.Code
                Date = event.DateTime.Date             
                NumberOfDocs = 1         
             }     

         Reduce = results => from result in results  
             group result by new 
             {
               result.Code,
               result.Date
             }
             into g
             select new Result 
             {
                Code = g.Key.Code
                Date = g.Key.DateTime.Date,
                NumberOfDocs = g.Sum(x => x.NumberOfDocs )
             }
```

and then query

```
List<Result> queryResults = session.Query< Result, <Index_Name> >()
                    .Where(x => x.Code == "some-code-number")
                    .ToList();
```

and then you can also do in your code

```
queryResults.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add something to the question. I need the Code to be passed as parameter to the function that performs the search, the value of "123" was just an example. Should I create an index for every search that requires a different value of Code?

Comment: Is that last GroupBy being done after the call to .ToList()? Is it possible to apply the GroupBy after the Where, without the need to resolve the query?

Comment: I created the index just as you suggested, and I got an error that it could not recognize the expression when I add the GroupBy after the Where.

Comment: Yes, the last GroupBy is done on queryResults after you get the results from ToList